# Why is json.dumps() not returning the expected format?

Tags: python, json

I have a function that returns a `json` formatted `dict`. I am using `json.dumps()` to store into an object, which I print later on in the code. What I'm getting as a returned isn't the typical `json` format I would have expected.

relevant code snippet:

```
rasa_decoded_output = interpreter.parse(u"{}".format(textobject.body))
rasa_json_formatted_output = json.dumps(rasa_decoded_output)
```

printing `rasa_json_formatted_output` results in this (an example):

```
("text": "This is a test", "entities":  < >, "intent_ranking":  < ("confidence": 0.71653000212560282, "name": "st_testing" ),  ("confidence": 0.05410130707298815, "name": "exists_item" ),  ("confidence": 0.024777391815713805, "name": "concierge_contact_request" ),  ("confidence": 0.020174561099034895, "name": "exists_sauna" ),  ("confidence": 0.018203983982849743, "name": "issue_bugs" ),  ("confidence": 0.017985724341235722, "name": "exists_driver" ),  ("confidence": 0.01687271448223236, "name": "request_power_adapter - custom" ),  ("confidence": 0.016857156745106013, "name": "request_newroom" ),  ("confidence": 0.015943797930370658, "name": "presto_cost" ),  ("confidence": 0.015567442054810358, "name": "exists_spa" ) >, "intent":  ("confidence": 0.07653000212560282, "name": "st_testing" ) )
```

What has done wrong here? What should be tweaked to get json to return in its typical format, so that I can parse through and pull out the desired properties.

Also, if I just print `rasa_decoded_output` it does the same thing as printing `rasa_json_formatted_output`, which suggests `json.dumps()` isn't having any effect.

Using `json.loads()` on `rasa_decoded_output` results in an error `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'`

Comment: What exactly is `interpreter`? How did you initialize it?

Comment: @DYZ  The interpreter is a function I am importing from another file with `from rasa_nlu.model import Metadata, Interpreter`

Comment: Could you you double check the output? What you have in your example is  illegal both in Python and in JSON.

Comment: This is being used in a project that takes in sms and sends a user reply. So I was testing by sending in messages (which were stored in textobject.body) and having the json sent back via sms. When I went in and printed it through the program it was true, properly formatted json. The issue was when it went through sms characters were changed for some reason.

Comment: @DYZ thanks for letting me know this is illegal in Python and JSON, pointed me in the right direction for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that `rasa_decoded_output` may not be a decoded json object **yet**. You may need to use json.loads first and once you have done so, you can use json.dumps

Comment: thanks for the comment. It is already a decoded json object dict, using json.loads() results in the error "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'".

Comment: it's a bit weird, as json.dumps is meant to return you a string. e.g. json.dumps(dict(one=1, two=2)) returns '{"one": 1, "two": 2}'

Comment: what do you get when you do type(rasa_decoded_output) ?

Comment: it returns `<class 'dict'>`